# Handling onClick with Databinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I am handling click event using data-binding,

Sometimes I am using method A way and it is working fine.

```
  android:onClick="@{myActivity.onIvEditClick()}"
```

Sometimes A is not working, so I have to use method B way

```
  android:onClick="@{() -> myActivity.onIvEditClick()}"
```

When to use way A or way B?

Comment: the only difference between A & B to work is whenever you are using A, the view has onClick registered with the signature of View.onClickListener but same can't be found for B i.e the signature of View.onClickListener

Answer (score 3):

1. **Method Reference:** A method can be referenced directly to event associated with any component eg. onClick(). Here the method will have a similar definition like the event. For example, if you are trying to bind on click event with any method let’s say onHandleClick() you must define it like this,

   `android:onClick="@{handlers::onHandleClick}"`
2. **Listener Binding:** Now what if I want to bind any method on a particular event on a component? My method could have any kind of definition which may not match with event method, and even I want to pass data though method. Let’s see how to achieve this.

   `android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.onSaveProfile(user)}"`

You can find more [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-data-binding-event-binding-part-2-5c0893480eef)